# Read data from array in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, wsdl2php

I'm accessing a WDSL web service and i just want to print the data in HTML

```
$answer2 = $client->call('GetApplicationFields2', array('aToken' => ($aToken)));

print_r($answer2);
```

Output ->

```
Array
(
    [GetCurrentVacanciesResult] => Array
        (
            [string] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 40|Developer
                    [1] => 56|Test
                )

        )

)
```

I want to print HTML like

```
<a href="40">Developer</a>
<a href="56">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$answer2 = $client->call('GetApplicationFields2', array('aToken' => ($aToken)));

foreach($answer2['GetCurrentVacanciesResult'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $s_key) {
        $temp = explode('|', $s_key);
        echo '<a href="'.$temp[0].'">'.$temp[1].'</a>';
    }
}
```

Result:

```
<a href="40">Developer</a>
<a href="56">Test</a>
<a href="100">Some other value</a>
<a href="200">One more</a>
```

Comment: how can i change the array. its comes from the web service

Comment: its works. but it can be any number of rows. so without using .$temp[0].'">'.$temp[1]... can u make that also in a loop. then i will mark your answer is correct

Comment: $temp[0] and $temp[1] has values: 40 and "Developer " because they are from explode function. Can you explain a bit better what would you like editing your original question with more sample data?

Comment: If the array had more rows it simply would have printed all.

Comment: thanks it works. :) thanks . i marked as its correct

Comment: Nice. I' m glad that I helped you.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach( $answer2["GetCurrentVacanciesResult"]["string"] as $row ) {
    $parts = explode( $row );
    echo '<a href="' . $parts[0] . '">' . $parts[ 1 ] . '</a>';
}
```